# Apple App Submission Questions

Tags: iphone

I'm about to submit my apple iOS app for the first time,
and have a few general questions regarding submission.

1) Can I choose the platform specifically, like iPad or iPhone, but not both?

2) My app runs well in general, but keeps receiving a warning at a certain point of the app, and often crashes. How strict is Apple with that, and could that be a cause of rejection?

3) What is the uploading process like? Do I get to manually upload all the classes and resources and frameworks, or is there a single magical way that uploads everything for me?

4) Is it required to have a website that supports the app? or can I just leave it blank?

*added:
5) if it gets rejected once, can I re-apply with the same app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It is a project setting. It will require some extra work on your part if you plan on releasing both an iPhone and iPad version (multiple xibs, etc).

2) Run your app through instruments and try to reduce memory leaks. Also, if you are dealing with large images in your app, do it sparingly and be sure to release everything properly (one of the main reasons for app crashes in my experience).

3) You'll build the app for release and have it signed with your developer certificate (Xcode will do this for you once you have it all setup). Then you'll run through the web interface filling out app information, uploading screenshots, and finally the zipped .app package which you built earlier. Make sure you don't have any spaces in the zip filename, and don't change your .app name.

4) You don't need a website for support, but it if is required just link to one of your personal sites (twitter, etc).

5) You can resubmit to your hearts content until Apple finally approves your app. But, you USUALLY won't have an issue with rejection unless you are doing something Apple has explicitly banned or your app is in such a bad state that the testers can't even test it.

Answer (score 1):

5) Yes you can resubmit, as many times as you want. You don't even have to increase the version number (except maybe for your own internal accounting). It depends on the cause of rejection though - if it's a bug you fixed, it's one thing; if it's a rejection because of policy violation, resubmission won't help you much.

Answer (score 1):

Before your app can be reviewed, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid Binary Architecture - iOS 3.0 introduced support for multiple binary architectures. If your binary is built for multiple architectures, your Info.plist must have a MinimumOSVersion key with a value of at least 3.0. Additionally, if your app is intended to support earlier iPhone and iPod touch models, your app must contain at least an armv6 binary; "thin" armv7-only binaries will not be accepted unless the armv7 required device capability is also present in the Info.plist UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key or the MinimumOSVersion key has a value of 4.3 or higher.

For more information, see Technical Q&A QA1707 at: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1707.html.

Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click Ready to Upload Binary. Continue through the submission process until the app status is Waiting for Upload and then use Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.

Answer (score 0):

1) You do it with your app.

2) If it crashes when they are testing it it will be rejected.

3) You build the app, zip it, and upload.

4) You have to put in some info. It should probably exist.